# no internal harddrive, i want to be able to still use the remaining space on 64gbflashdrive

Tags: installation, 12.10

i have no internal hard-drive, i currently am using my brothers flash drive to run Ubuntu and i have a 64gb flash drive but would like to still use the flash drives remaining space once Ubuntu is installed. is this possible or am i forever doomed to only be able to run Ubuntu on it and never use it for anything else at the same time, like an internal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to allocate some of the space on the flash drive for use like a normal thumb drive in addition to booting Ubuntu, you could use gparted to resize your partition and format it as FAT16 or FAT 32. I'm not sure I would really recommend doing this however, as I would not want to risk having my bootable disk corrupted by connecting it to various systems.

gparted is available in the Ubuntu Software Center or you can install it from Terminal using

`sudo apt-get install gparted`

Comment: thank you and it is running but i have only one problem now, it freezes when i click on things but i believe it has to do with the fact that i am using only my usb flash drive.the freezing resolves itself within seconds but it does get a little annoying.